# Yii zii.widgets.CDetailView

Tags: php, yii

I want to show two models attributes in Groups view file in zii.widgets.CDetailView.

```
My database is like this
   =========  Group ==========
   id
   name

   ========= Memebr ==========
   id
   group_id
   firstname
   lastname
```

I used this

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
  'data'=>$model,
  'attributes'=>array(
    'id',
    'name',
    array(
      'label' => 'firstname',
      $member->getAttributeLabel('firstname'),
    ),
  ),
)
); ?>
```

But its not working at all. I followed this [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/9834-cdetailview-and-model-relations/) but not got any good result. Any help and suggestions will be higly appreciable.

Comment: according to your models, there will be many members belonging to the same group, so do you want to display a list of firstnames of members belonging to a particular group? or you want to do something else? Also are you passing `$member` to the view from the controller? if yes then how are you assigning that $member? Semantically speaking, in the detail view of group, one should be able to see all the members in that group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
  'data'=>$model,
  'attributes'=>array(
    'id',
    'name',
    array(
      'label' => 'Firstname',
      'value' => $member->firstname,
    ),
```

As Yii already have loaded the second model in your first model so you don't need to use render partial in the view file.
Let me know if you face any error.